# How can I find a witness to the relation n! is O(n^n)?

Tags: complexity-theory

If I take k = 0, then n > 1, then after that I multiply both sides by n^(n-1).. 
so it becomes n^n > n^(n-1).. but I can't find n! here to get witnesses.. 
Please help!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve]. [edit] the question to add more details, code, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question, not programming question.

Comment: `O(n!) = O(n**n/exp(n)*sqrt(n))`

Comment: @MikeCAT I think this is talking about Big-O notation, which IS a programming question (only one that happens to be highly linked to maths!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Maybe retag this question. AFAIK it has nothing to do with any of the above tags (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I'm new here, I didn't know what to do with them, I mentioned there BigO, it gave me an erroe

Answer (score 1):

Actually `O(n!)` is *less* than `O(n**n)` since

```
  O(n!) = O(n**n * sqrt(n) / exp(n))
```

Which can be obtained from *Stirling's approximation*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Also from Wiki: [`The statement f(n)=O(n!) is sometimes weakened to f(n)=O\left(n^n\right) to derive simpler formulas for asymptotic complexity. For any k>0 and c>0, O(n^c(\log n)^k) is a subset of O(n^{c+\varepsilon }) for any \varepsilon >0, so may be considered as a polynomial with some bigger order.`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) Best to look at that on Wiki due to the special characters...

Comment: But, how can I prove this relation through witnesses?? As I mentioned in details, I couldn't find the witnesses..

Comment: @FahadRehman You probably would be better off asking that on http://math.stackexchange.com/